# bootstrapvalidator submit button not allowed after validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, bootstrapvalidator

I'm running a form with bootstrapValidator.

If I submit the form while there are still validation errors (for example, I forgot to input one of the fields), even when I finish filling all the form fields properly, the submit button maintains the "cursor: not-allowed" style that it got from the initial submission:

```
<form id="invoice_form" class="well form-horizontal" action="submit.php" method="post" data-toggle="validator"">
    <fieldset>
        ...
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: left;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" > send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thanks,

David

Edit:
I didn't succeed to run my code on fiddle, but I was able to locate the problem:
when I use the following code to force a value into one of the fields (service drop down calls the function to set the amount), the amount field remains considered invalid (label doesn't change to green), although the form can be submitted:
`<script>
function showAmount() {
    var amounts = {
                    "service_a": "300",
                    "service_b": "450",
                    "service_c": "500",
                    "other": ""
    };
    var x = document.getElementById("service").value;
    document.getElementById("amountDiv").style.display = "block";
    if (x != ''){
        document.getElementById("amount").value = parseInt(amounts[x]);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("amount").value = '';
    }
}
</script>`

It seems to me that I need to manually run the validation on the forced value, once the value is entered...

Any suggestion on if and how it can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Please make a fiddle link for this issue

Comment: `$('#amount').trigger('input');`

after

`document.getElementById("amount").value = parseInt(amounts[x]);`
did the trick for me :-)